# Irreducible $3$-manifolds with boundary

Tags: smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

A $3$-manifold $M$ (without boundary) is irreducible if every smoothly embedded $2$-sphere in $M$ bounds a $3$-ball.

What would be a “good” definition of irreducibility for $3$-manifolds with boundary? Is it necessary to add extra requirements?

For example, let $M = \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus B$, where $B$ is an open ball. I would like $M$ to be irreducible. However, if $B’$ is a ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that contains $B$, then its boundary does not bound a ball in $M$, so $M$ is not irreducible according to the original definition.

Comment: You could require that every boundary component was a sphere, and that after filling them in, you got an irreducible manifold.

Comment: You can say that a 2-sphere $S$ in $M$ is inessential if it either bounds a ball or is isotopic to a boundary component of $M$. Then call $M$ irreducible if every sphere in $M$ is inessential. This definition is similar to the one of an atoroidal manifold.